# How to define thread-local local static variables?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, static, thread-safety

How to define local static variables (that keeps its value between function calls) that are not shared among different threads?

I am looking for an answer both in C and C++

Comment: What OS are you using? TLS is not portable between unixen and windows.

Comment: C++11 introduces another storage duration called [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Try using it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Both C++11 *and* C11. In C11, it's `_Thread_local`, unless you also include `<threads.h>` (which adds a `#define` to `thread_local`, as is usual for C99 and later).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

on Windows using Windows API: [TlsAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/TlsSetValue()/TlsGetValue()

on Windows using compiler intrinsic: use [_declspec(thread)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx)

on Linux (other POSIX???) : [get_thread_area()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/get_thread_area) and related

Comment: after reading on MSDN, Tls functions are exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Just use static and __thread in your function.

Example:

```
int test(void)
{
        static __thread a;

        return a++;
}
```

Comment: @Ali: no, it's an extension provided by GCC and a few other compilers.  On MSVC, I think you use `__declspec(thread)` instead.

Comment: __thread works on linux, bsd, aix, and with the xl_c, gcc, and many other compilers.   it can be trivially #defined to __declspec(thread) on windows.

Comment: It does not work with gcc or clang on macOS because it requires operating system support.

Answer (score 2):

The current C standard has no model for threads or alike, so you can't get an answer, there.

The utility foreseen by POSIX for that is `pthread_[gs]etspecific`.

The next version of the C standard adds threads and has a concept of *thread local storage*.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the C++11 thread local storage additions if you have access to C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own thread specific local storage as singleton per thread ID. Something like this:

```
struct ThreadLocalStorage
{
    ThreadLocalStorage()
    {
        // initialization here
    }
    int my_static_variable_1;
    // more variables
};

class StorageManager
{
    std::map<int, ThreadLocalStorage *> m_storages;

    ~StorageManager()
    {   // storage cleanup
        std::map<int, ThreadLocalStorage *>::iterator it;
        for(it = m_storages.begin(); it != m_storages.end(); ++it)
            delete it->second;
    }

    ThreadLocalStorage * getStorage()
    {
        int thread_id = GetThreadId();
        if(m_storages.find(thread_id) == m_storages.end())
        {
            m_storages[thread_id] = new ThreadLocalStorage;
        }

        return m_storages[thread_id];
    }

public:
    static ThreadLocalStorage * threadLocalStorage()
    {
        static StorageManager instance;
        return instance.getStorage();
    }
};
```

GetThreadId(); is a platform specific function for determining caller's thread id. Something like this:

```
int GetThreadId()
{
    int id;
#ifdef linux
    id = (int)gettid();
#else  // windows
    id = (int)GetCurrentThreadId();
#endif
    return id;
}
```

Now, within a thread function you can use it's local storage:

```
void threadFunction(void*)
{
  StorageManager::threadLocalStorage()->my_static_variable_1 = 5; //every thread will have
                                                           // his own instance of local storage.
}
```

Comment: You'll also need synchronisation (such as a read/write mutex) to protect `m_storages` from access by multiple threads.

Comment: Not only m_storages, but also std::map and the locally "static StorageManager instance;" is not thread safe.
In native code implement a high efficiency singleton is not a easy task, see "C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking" by Scott Meyers and Andrei Alexandrescu. http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf