# Declare, allocate and deallocate thread-local pointer variables outside the run loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a threaded pipe-and-filter implementation where I want to use thread-local copies in one of my filters. I do not implement a run loop myself. Instead, the base Filter class calls a process() method on each of the filters whenever it gets data to be processed.

I have two issues with using thread_locals in this scenario:
1) I cannot declare thread_locals within the process() method, because the point is to reuse the thread locals whenever the process() method is called.

Example code below:

```
void process(SomeInput in) {
    thread_local SomeClass* someClass = nullptr;
    if (someClass == nullptr) someClass = new SomeClass(params);

    // do stuff here...
}
```

So above I initialize a thread_local instance of SomeClass. But I do not deallocate it, because process() will be called by the same thread's run loop whenever new data arrives. Obviously, it the classes will never get freed. Bad.

2) I've added a threadCleanup() method to the filter implementation which gets now called whenever a filter is stopped (and it's thread(s) are stopped). Though that would require to declare thread_local member variables like:

```
class SomeFilter : public Filter <...> {
// ...
private:
    thread_local SomeClass* _someClass;
}
```

But that doesn't work with classes and throws:
"thread_local is only allowed on variable declarations"

What is the proper way to declare, allocate and deallocate thread-locals in such scenario?

Comment: What's the point of having `thread_local` local automatic variable? Answer - no point at all.

Comment: What happens when your function is used by more than one "cleanup pool"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering with fix for your original problem instead of the new one you created for yourself:

Just make the original code use `std::unique_ptr`. You can even one-line it, [since `thread_local` implies `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794640/364696), so it will only be initialized once without needing to perform per call tests for `nullptr`:

```
void process(SomeInput in) {
    thread_local std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someClass(new SomeClass(params));

    // do stuff here...
}
```

The first time any given thread calls `process`, the `unique_ptr` is initialized for that thread; when that thread exits, the `unique_ptr` is destroyed and the `SomeClass` instance for that thread is collected, [because `thread_local` destructors are called on thread exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794640/364696).

Mind you, if `someClass` is small, you could store it directly in `thread_local` storage instead of storing the `unique_ptr` there pointing to the heap, which would let you avoid `unique_ptr` entirely, since as noted, `thread_local` implies `static` and calls destructors on thread exit:

```
void process(SomeInput in) {
    thread_local SomeClass someClass(params);

    // do stuff here,
    // using someClass. instead of someClass-> for member/method access,
    // and &someClass where you used to use someClass if something needs a raw
    // pointer (the raw pointer is definitely sticking around until thread
    // exit after all)
}
```

Using the `unique_ptr` approach might still be advantageous (thread local storage can be limited/slow, so it may be worthwhile to store the rest of the class in normal heap memory).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are looking for is `static thread_local` on a member variable:

```
class SomeFilter : public Filter <...> {
// ...
private:
    static thread_local SomeClass* _someClass;
}
```

Rather than performing manual cleanup it would be better to encapsulate `_someClass` in a `unique_ptr`, since thread locals are destroyed on thread exit:

```
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> _someClass;
```