# Return pointer to vector's data without copying buffer and memory leaks

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-leaks

The question should be fairly simple, but I'm not a C++ programmer.

So imagine I have a `std::vector` filled with something as a local variable in a function. What I want to do is to return pointer to that data and count from that function, but not the vector itself (because it goes to another language, not C++). So what is the best way to do it?

I bet I can declare vector with `new` keyword, but when I later call `free()` on its `pointer data`, will there be a leak?

I can also `malloc()` new buffer, copy vector's buffer into that and return fresh one, but I wish I can avoid that.

Comment: How do you send the data to the other language? Can you just return the vector itself and then send the internal pointer of the returned vector using `v.data()`?

Comment: The `vector` must live somewhere while the other language is using it. You either need to not return from the function until the other language is done or move the `vector` into some persistent space or give the responsibility of keeping the `vector` alive to the other language. Any of these solutions would work, but your question doesn't contain enough information to know which one is appropriate.

Comment: `malloc` with `free`, and `new` with `delete`. Don't cross those streams. And don't try to delete the `vector`'s data from under its nose; that's not nice.

Comment: Declarate vector outside the the function. Pass pointer or link on the vector into function. Fill the vector inside function. You don't need to call "new"/"delete" - the vector is doing it instead you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your function with the `std::vector<T>&` as an argument and return only the `vector.count()` (See [Pass by reference in C++](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbclx01/cplr233.htm)). Latter, in client code pass an empty constructed vector to that function.

To get pointer to raw data, you can use `&vector[0]` or `&vector.front()`. Starting from C++11, there are a newly added member function in `vector`:  [data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), which returns the address of the initial element in the container.

In general, don't use unnecessary `malloc/free` operations and avoid the use of **heap allocation** when it is not necessary. Consider **smart pointers** instead of raw pointers and `make_shared/make_unique` instead of explicit `new`.

Comment: `std::pair<std::vector<T>, int>>` makes no sense. You can already use `vector.size()`. Did you mean `std::pair<int *, int>>` to fake an `array_view` or `span`?

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that the count is something else than vector's count

Comment: Thanks, so basically it is impossible to do what I wanted! Still upvoted

Answer (score 0):

If your vector contains basic types (for example int) and you know the memory will be deallocated with free you can just use:

```
if(v.empty()) return NULL;
int* retResut;
retResut= reinterpret_cast<int*>(std::malloc(v.size() * sizeof(int)));
std::memcpy(retResut,v.data(),v.size()* sizeof(int));
return retResut
```

Comment: The question explicitly states "without memory leaks".

Comment: @nwp from original question: "but when I later call free()" so I assumed calling free later is an option.

Comment: That's the option I considered in the question intself, but thanks! As far as I can see my question has only one answer: "impossible"

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you need to declare a function that has the following definition: `SomeType* foo();`. You can used [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a raw pointer to the data (c++11). In case of c++03 you can use `&my_vector[0]` (and you must check for empty vector in order to avoid runtime debug aserts)

There is one thing to take into consideration; is it called from multiple 
threads or not:

1. when you have only one thread calling `foo`:

   ```
   std::vector<SomeType>& get_buffer()
   {
       static std::vector<SomeType> data;
       return data;
   }
   SomeType* foo()
   {
       std::vector<SomeType>& buffer = get_buffer();
       buffer.clear();

       //fill buffer with stuff with push_back

       return buffer.data();
   }
   ```
2. When called from multiple threads. The static variable is [initialized properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11) however the push_back function is not thread safe. You also need a different buffer for each thread but this does not guarantee total safely (considering you have no way of knowing how long the lifetime of that data should be). `get_buffer` should return a unique `std::vector` for the each thread. You can use [thread local storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) by changing `static` into `thread_local` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794382/are-c11-thread-local-variables-automatically-static)):

   ```
   std::vector<SomeType>& get_buffer()
   {
       thread_local std::vector<SomeType> data;
       return data;
   }
   ```

   Node that `thread_local` is since `c++11` if you are using c++03 you need to use boost library or platform specific code.