# Do all const objects have static storage duration?

Tags: c++, static, constants, language-lawyer, storage-duration

I wonder if all constants in C++ have static duration, even though they are created inside a function other than `main()`?

For example:

```cpp
const int a = 3;     

int main()
{
    const int b = 4;
}
```

What is the difference between `a` and `b`?

Comment: what do you mean by static duration ?

Comment: I know that string literals do, I've seen a question related to that. Don't know if that applies to other simple types but I suspect it does. It's actually a good question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Other kinds of literals (other than user-defined literals) do not occupy any memory in the abstract machine, and have no storage duration.

Comment: If you're talking about constant variables instead of literals, no AFAIK. Why would it be like that? It's perfectly normal to have constant variables to not be initialized to compile-time constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether an object is `const` and whether it has static storage duration are unrelated. An object defined inside a function has automatic storage duration unless explicitly marked `static` or `thread_local`. A static data member of a class has static storage duration unless explicitly marked `thread_local`. An object defined at namespace scope has static storage duration unless explicitly marked `thread_local`.

Comment: It is further useful to understand about static storage duration and thread storage duration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794382/are-c11-thread-local-variables-automatically-static and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score 1):

No; this is clearest if you create a `const` object with a constructor and destructor, which will be called when the program enters and leaves the scope in which the automatic `const` object is declared.  The `const` automatic variable can also have different values on each invocation of the function, based on the parameters or other runtime data, while a `static const` local variable could not.

A `constexpr` object, however, cannot have non-trivial constructor or destructor or be initialized to anything but constants known at compile time, so it could be implemented the same way as a `static` variable.