# Is it legal to return a thread_local reference from a function?

Tags: c++

Returning a reference from a static like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-the-singleton-pattern-thread-safe) is legal C++

```cpp
static int& from_static() {
     static int x;
     return x;
}
```

Everything looks swell so far. But would it also be legal, if the `static` variable inside the function was `thread_local` instead?

```cpp
static int& from_thread_local() {
     thread_local int x;
     return x;
}
```

Actually, I'm pretty sure it is. But mixing the `static` keyword in the declaration of the function with the `thread_local` from the variable declaration somehow doesn't sparkle with me.

Comment: I'm sorry, if I misused any C++ vocabulary. I didn't learn the language by reading the standard.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be OK? As long as the reference is not used after the calling thread terminates, it should be fine, the memory is still valid. The `static` on the function just means the function doesn't have a `this` parameter if it is a member of a class, or it has local linkage if it is standalone function. That doesn't affect the memory that the function is able to access. Applying `static` or `thread_local` on the local `x` variable inside the function dictates its lifetime, not its access rights.

Comment: You can return a reference to whatever you want, as long as it's lifetime exceeds that of the function call. The only thing that doesn't achieve that by default is a variable with automatic storage associated with the function's scope (local objects). `thread_local` does not have automatic storage so this usage is fine for the same reasons `static` is fine.

Comment: Learning C++ from reading the Standard is one of the harder ways to learn the language. Better than Trial and Error, I suppose, but much harder than a good text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you are using it.  `thread_local` storage duration lasts for the life time of the thread that created the variable.  So, if this function was called by a thread then `x` would live until that thread exited.  If you ran `from_thread_local` in it's own thread then it would not be safe as you wouldn't get the value until after the thread ends and the lifetime of `x` has ended.

The `static` on the function level has no effect on this since in that context `static` describes the linkage of the function, not the duration when it is a free function.  If it is a member function then it just describes that no instance of the class is needed to call the function.

Comment: _static describes the linkage of the function, not the duration_ Many thanks for reminding me

Comment: @nada No problem.  Doesn't help the C++ likes to reuse keywords.  Unfortunately `intern` or `internal` was never reserved so they couldn't make a common sense identifier.

Comment: In the case of the Meyers singleton (the topic of the post referenced by the OP) the `static` keyword is used inside a class, so it doesn't even affect the linkage of the function.

Comment: @Brian I wasn't thinking about member function but I have now added that in.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking two questions:

1. Is it ok to return a reference to a local `thread_local` variable?
2. What happens when you return a reference to a local `thread_local` variable from a `static` function?

The answer to question 1 is yes. The variable will outlive the function call, so the reference will be usable. (However, there are some obvious cases where this is not true, *e.g.,* do not use the return value from such a function if you are wrapping it in a `packaged_task` that you are going to execute in another thread.)

The answer to question 2 is: the fact that the function is `static` has no effect on the meaning of the `thread_local` local variable. In the case of the Meyers singleton, the `static` specifier just means the function doesn't require an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is [still legal C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794640/4454124).

However keep in mind that the reference you're returning is to a variable that is local to the thread, not to the function. So you need to take care not to exchange the reference between threads, or if you do you must ensure not to use it after the originating thread exits.