# thread_local static variables in a dynamic loaded library – when are they created?

Tags: c++, dynamic-loading, thread-local-storage

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) states the following on `thread_local` variables

> The storage for the object is allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage duration.

I think of using a `thread_local static` member variable declared inside a shared library that is loaded at runtime via `dlopen` / `LoadLibrary`. Since it's totally possible that there are already quite a few threads running at the timepoint this library is loaded and some of them will then access that variable later, I wonder how this works if the storage is allocated when the thread begins? If the variable does not exist in the program at the timepoint the thread is created this obviously cannot work as explained there. Furthermore it seems like a waste of resources if a process running e.g. 100 threads would create an instance of that thread local variable for each of those threads if only a few of them would actually access the variable.

So, is the documentation incorrect here or are there chances that what I'm trying here might lead to undefined behavior? If the documentation is simply incorrect, where can I find a reliable description of what can be expected in reality? In case it's implementation defined, I'm particularly interested how clang handles it on macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What cppreference says is paraphrased. What's actually in [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.stc.thread) is

> All variables declared with the `thread_local` keyword have *thread storage duration*. The storage for these
> entities lasts for the duration of the thread in which they are created. There is a distinct object or reference
> per thread, and use of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.

There's nothing in there about when, exactly, the storage is allocated, just that it lasts for the duration of the thread. This means it could be allocated when the thread is created, or when the variable is first used, or possibly a combination of both.

The variable may not be constructed (I assume this is what you mean when you say "create an instance") when the storage is allocated. That depends on where and how the variable is defined. But, if it is constructed, it won't be destroyed until the thread ends.

Support for dynamically loading libraries via `dlopen` or `LoadLibrary` is a compiler/platform extension, and not part of the language. How that interacts with `thread_local` would also be platform specific.

Comment: [Useful supplementary reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794640/4581301).