# Execute piece of code once per thread in OpenMP without default constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, boost-thread

I try to write a parallel for loop using openMP V.2.0. In the middle of the parallel region I construct an Object which I would like to be constructed once per thread.

```
 #pragma omp parallel for 
  for (long i = 0; i < static_cast<long>(general_triangles.size()); ++i)
  {
      TrianglePointer tri = general_triangles[i];
      if (tri.GetClassification() == TO_CLASSIFY)
      {
          bool tri_has_correct_normal = true;
          // --- Construct tree once per thread ---
          Tree tree(*(gp_boolean_operator->mp_group_manager));
          if (tree.IsTriangleExternal(tri, tri_has_correct_normal))
          {
              tri.SetClassification(IS_EXTERNAL);
          }
      }
  }
```

Is there any keyword for constructing tree once per thread?

Do you suggest to use bood_thread_ptr instead?

Comment: Why would you cast `i` to a `long` instead of just using a `std::size_t`?

Comment: @erip because size_t is not supported by openMP v.2.0

Comment: Very sensible response. :) TIL -- seems silly, but alas.

Comment: I'm not sure that you really have a problem here at all. As your code is written, Tree is a local variable and will be constructed separately in each thread, once in each thread each time that the conditions are true (just as you construct multiple instances in the serial code). 

So, please explain better what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: You misunderstood it I think. The parallel for may loop a million times even though there are just two threads. He wants to make each thread construct the object once instead of half a million times.

Comment: @Jim Cownie, Actually for the sequential case, tree is constructed once outside the loop. However, here I would like to construct it once per each thread for the parallel case.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Consider untested code like this :

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
// --- Construct one tree in each per thread ---
  Tree tree(*(gp_boolean_operator->mp_group_manager));

#pragma omp for
  for (long i = 0; i < static_cast<long>(general_triangles.size()); ++i)
  {
      TrianglePointer tri = general_triangles[i];
      if (tri.GetClassification() == TO_CLASSIFY)
      {
          bool tri_has_correct_normal = true;

          if (tree.IsTriangleExternal(tri, tri_has_correct_normal))
          {
              tri.SetClassification(IS_EXTERNAL);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

It shows that you can do all this inside portable, OS independent, OpenMP, and that you don't introduce an unnecessary static variable.

Comment: Wouldn t this result in each thread peforming duplicate work by having each one executing the whole for loop?

Comment: No. The loop has `#pragma omp for` so the iterations are distributed over the threads. (`omp parallel for` is merely a syntactic convenience that combines the two directives. Here we do not want them combined.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
gcc: static __thread

MSVC: static __declspec(thread)
```

However, for performance reasons it might be better to handle it manually. Use a vector with size that corresponds to the number of threads, and use the thread number to index the vector. If the element is NULL, the thread must construct it.

Also read: [How to define thread-local local static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606624/how-to-define-thread-local-local-static-variables)

Something like this (please note that it is untested, and I never use OMP myself because it does not offer the degree of control that I prefer to have over what actually happens).

```
 std::vector<Tree *> trees;
 trees.resize(omp_get_thread_limit());

 #pragma omp parallel for 
  for (long i = 0; i < static_cast<long>(general_triangles.size()); ++i)
  {
      TrianglePointer tri = general_triangles[i];
      if (tri.GetClassification() == TO_CLASSIFY)
      {
          bool tri_has_correct_normal = true;
          // --- Construct tree once per thread ---
          Tree *& tree = trees[omp_get_thread_num()];
          if (tree == NULL)
              tree = new Tree(*(gp_boolean_operator->mp_group_manager));
          if (tree->IsTriangleExternal(tri, tri_has_correct_normal))
          {
              tri.SetClassification(IS_EXTERNAL);
          }
      }
  }

  // delete trees afterwards
```

Comment: There is no need to step outside OpenMP.

Comment: Yes there is (or may be) a need, because the "static" keyword will cause the compiler to insert a mutex which will slow down the processing tremendously.

Comment: Tree &* tree ? Are u sure?

Comment: sorry should be *&. Maybe you can construct all the threads before the loop instead?