# Are JNI functions thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface, thread-safety, openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP to parallelize the process of converting an Array of Java Strings into a C array of strings (char**):

```
char** convert(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray jstringArray, int n_threads){

        int n_rows =(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jstringArray);
        char **cArray = (char **) malloc(n_rows * sizeof(char*));
        int i=0;
        jstring row;

        if(n_threads <= 0 ) n_threads = 1;
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads) private(i, row)
        for (i=0; i<n_rows; i++) {
                  row = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jstringArray, i);
                  cArray[i] = (char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, row, 0);
                  printf("cArray[%d]: %s thread:%d row:%p env:%p jstringArray:%p\n", i, cArray[i], omp_get_thread_num(), row, env, jstringArray);
        }

        return cArray;
}
```

However, it seems I am running into a race condition when obtaining the jstring rows:

**Output for n_threads = 1:**

```
cArray[0]: AA thread:0 row:0x7f5b1c000c90 env:0x7f5b300091f8 jstringArray:0x7f5bb3ffdc38
cArray[1]: BB thread:0 row:0x7f5b1c000c98 env:0x7f5b300091f8 jstringArray:0x7f5bb3ffdc38
cArray[2]: CC thread:0 row:0x7f5b1c000ca0 env:0x7f5b300091f8 jstringArray:0x7f5bb3ffdc38
cArray[3]: DD thread:0 row:0x7f5b1c000ca8 env:0x7f5b300091f8 jstringArray:0x7f5bb3ffdc38
```

**Output for n_threads = 3:**

```
cArray[0]: AA thread:0 row:0x7f434c004050 env:0x7f434800a9f8 jstringArray:0x7f435b8f0c48
cArray[1]: BB thread:0 row:0x7f434c004060 env:0x7f434800a9f8 jstringArray:0x7f435b8f0c48
cArray[2]: **CC** thread:1 **row:0x7f434c004058** env:0x7f434800a9f8 jstringArray:0x7f435b8f0c48
cArray[3]: **CC** thread:2 **row:0x7f434c004058** env:0x7f434800a9f8 jstringArray:0x7f435b8f0c48
```

The conflicting function seems to be GetObjectArrayElement(), which returns the same reference for two different threads (1 and 2 on the example) and for 2 diferent array indexes (2 and 3).

Is this behaviour inherent to said JNI function, or am I missing something?

Comment: Declaring the loop variable i in private list looks suspicious.

Comment: @AlexF I know that it is private by default

Comment: You can only make JNI calls on a thread that has been attached to the JVM.

Comment: @AlexCohn this was actually very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Which platform/JVM is that?

Comment: @AlexCohn JRE 8. I've fixed it by attaching each thread to the JVM.

Comment: Method declaration in Java is unclear: static, synchronized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the `#pragma omp parallel ...` and `#pragma omp for ...` directives to do actions in parallel but not in a loop.  See [Execute piece of code once per thread in OpenMP without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586798/execute-piece-of-code-once-per-thread-in-openmp-without-default-constructor) for a similar problem.

Something like this should work (untested, so you may have to recode somewhat as I suspect the `private` directives might be located improperly):

```
char** convert(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray jstringArray, int n_threads)
{

    int n_rows =(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jstringArray);
    char **cArray = (char **) malloc(n_rows * sizeof(char*));
    int i=0;
    jstring row;

    JavaVM* jvm = NULL;
    JNIEnv *thr_env;

    ( *env )->GetJavaVM( env, &jvm );

    if(n_threads <= 0 ) n_threads = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(n_threads)  private( thr_env )
    {
        // attach this thread to the JVM
        ( *jvm )->AttachCurrentThread( jvm, ( void** ) &thr_env, NULL );
        // run the for loop
        #pragma omp for private(i, row)
        for (i=0; i<n_rows; i++)
        {
             row = (jstring)
                 (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jstringArray, i);
             cArray[i] = (char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, row, 0);
             printf(
                 "cArray[%d]: %s thread:%d row:%p env:%p jstringArray:%p\n",
                 i, cArray[i], omp_get_thread_num(), row, env, jstringArray);
        }
        ( *jvm )->DetachCurrentThread( jvm );
    }

    return cArray;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried something similar as I've posted before and it does work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've never worked with JNI before, but a rudimentary google search of "JNI thread safety" returned [this](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/sync.html) as its first hit:

> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv *) is only valid in the current thread. You must not pass the interface pointer from one thread to another, or cache an interface pointer and use it in multiple threads. The Java Virtual Machine will pass you the same interface pointer in consecutive invocations of a native method from the same thread, but different threads pass different interface pointers to native methods.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to attach each thread to the JVM before accesing the JNI functions, like so:

```
JavaVM* jvm = NULL;
JNIEnv *t_env;

(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(n_threads) private(t_env)
{
  (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void**)&t_env, NULL);

  // Call JNI functions here using t_env...

  (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
}
```

Comment: Attach/Detach are rather expensive, I won't recommend calling them in a tight loop. The catch is that with OpenMP, you don't have command of underlying thread creation and destruction. Maybe, this means that some other, more explicit multithreading frameworks should be used for JNI.

Comment: @AlexCohn I am defining a parallel region, not a loop. So, shouldn't each thread call AttachCurrentThread() and DetachCurrentThread() only once according to this snippet?

Comment: @cppstudy  *I am defining a parallel region, not a loop.* `#pragma omp parallel for ...` immediately followed by a `for (...)` defines a loop.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm refering to the snippet I've posted on this answer, which is where Alex has placed his comment. The for loop would go as a #pragma omp for between the AttachCurrentThread() and DetachCurrentThread() calls, as you have specified in your answer.

Comment: @cppstudy Oh.  I thought you were referring back to the original code in the question.