# Are static variables automatically thread local?

Tags: c, c11, thread-local

Are local `static` variables automatically thread local, or are they shared between threads?

```
void f() {
    static int x; // <-- need explicit _Thread_local ?
}
```

Comment: No, they're not. That's why you need to do it explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606624/how-to-define-thread-local-local-static-variables

Comment: The answer to the first part of your question is 'no'; the answer to the second part would be the inverse of that (so, 'yes'). The answer to the question in code comments is, 'only if you want it to be thread-local'.

Comment: [`thread_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was `static` for block-scope variables before the C language specification acknowledged threads  or had any support for them, much less `_Thread_local` specifically.  In that context, when  not combined with `_Thread_local`, it specifies *static storage duration*, meaning that the variable comes into existence (as if) at the beginning of program execution and exists and maintains its last-stored value for the entire run of the program.  An object with static storage duration is shared by all threads.

On the other hand, `_Thread_local` always specifies *thread storage duration*, which means that the object so declared exists and maintains its last-stored value for the entire lifetime of a thread, and that the declared identifier designates a different object in each thread.  When an object is declared `_Thread_local` at block scope, it must also bear either the `extern` or `static` qualifier, which conveys its *linkage* -- external or none.

`extern` declarations of any kind at block scope are unusual, but they do occasionally serve a useful purpose.  Most of the time, though, `static _Thread_local` is what you will want for thread-local, block-scope variables.

Answer (score 2):

`static` and `_Thread_local` specify two different things.

A variable declared as `static` has *static storage duration* and has full program lifetime.  A variable declared `_Thread_local` has *thread storage duration* and an instance of it exists for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

They are shared value between threads. As you already mentioned by yourself, if you want to make have independently value for each of thread then declare it something line that `_Thread_local static int x;`